# URxvt has lags in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, 13.04, zsh

I use urxvt as my default terminal and zsh as default shell. I use this two tools everywhere, but after today upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04 I got some lags in term.

Lags means - when I type command, term doesn't show last character, up/down through history, prompt doesn't updates with right command (can leave the same or jump few commands back)

This is only with zsh, not in bash.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you try `zsh -f` and see if this also has lags?